# YouTube Studio Multiple Camera Angles

Tags: youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

YouTube recently forced everyone to the new YouTube studio for live streaming.  Per their documentation here https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853812?hl=en the only place to setup Multiple Camera angles is on the Events page.  However, since their change I can't access Classic Streaming anymore, it just pop ups a message saying

> Live Control Room is the new way to go live.

I've tried reaching out to YouTube directly - I'm stuck in a support loop of uselessness.  Has anyone else seen this and found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct email from YouTube:

> I just want to make all a clarification regarding your concern why you can't find to stream with multiple camera angles.
>
> Due because of low usage and since it can't be watched on mobile,
> multi-camera won't migrate to Live Control Room right now. Rest
> assured we are looking for a better version of this product in the
> near future.
>
> We also recommend you to send a feedback to our Product team so they
> can look into your suggestion.
>
> Thanks for your understanding on this matter.  Let me know if you have
> other questions.

Comment: Coming up on two years ago; Bummer.

Comment: We hacked around this by adding links/buttons to our website to flip the embedded video - might be an option for you as well